# call multiple params in onClick React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-props

I need to pass onTaskShow, getColumnId params to OnClick. But do not know how to do it correctly.

```
export default({
  column,
  onTaskShow,
  getColumnId
}) => (
  <div className="column">
    <button type="button" class=" addBtn btn btn-success" onClick={onTaskShow, getColumnId}>Add Task</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a function that use all the function that you need:

```
onClick={()=>{
   onTaskShow();
   getColumnId();
   }
}
```

If you need the `event`:

```
onClick={(e)=>{
   onTaskShow(e);
   getColumnId(e);
   }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do this in React. An event can be handled by one function. you can do this

```
onClick={()=>{
   onTaskShow();
   getColumnId();
   }
```